# Arguments to __init__ when using a subclass and super

Tags: python, parent-child, super

I'm spending a nice Saturday looking a bit deeper into Python objects, and had a simple question that isn't mindblowing but kinda curious.

Say I have a base class and a subclass [as follows](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php):

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.firstname = first
        self.lastname = last

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname + " " + self.lastname

class Employee(Person):

    def __init__(self, first, last, staffnum):
        super().__init__(first, last)
        self.staffnumber = staffnum


x = Person("Marge", "Simpson")
y = Employee("Homer", "Simpson", "1007")
```

I'm looking at the Employee class.

Given:
we are using `super()`  and it has arguments in it,
why in python does the `__init__`still require us to type `first, last`?
Shouldn't this be inferred from our use of super? Seems like extra repetitive typing. What's the reasoning for the author having to do this?

Comment: What if you wanted to use `super().__init__(first, staffname)` for example where `staffname` comes after `staffnum`?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is so you can further customize subclasses. In your example, when you still want to input `first` and `last` it is more of a hassle because you have to type it twice, like this:

```
class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        super().__init__(first, last)

emp1 = Employee("Bob", "Jones")
```

However, you might want to autofill some of those values. In this example maybe a `FamilyMember` class where the last name is common.

```
class FamilyMember(Person):
    def __init__(self, first):
        super().__init__(first, last="Erikson")

fm1 = FamilyMember("Paul")
```

In this case you would only need to input the `first` variable for a `FamilyMember` and the `last` variable would be automatically filled in.

Comment: so, a subclass is supposed to be selective and written to allow you to pick and choose what you want from the base class...

Comment: and when you say 'autofill', is there a more technical name for that? It's been 'overridden'?

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck I've heard default value, but I don't know if that is the official name for it.

Comment: While this doesn't make a whole lot of sense in the example you gave, I've used it a decent amount in game development. I usually have a base Entity class with ennemies, moveable objects, and players branching off of it. In that case I may set the default value of the image for enemies so I don't have to retype it in each object, for example.